# I flutter_map, how to handle map dragged away from user marker?

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I use a combination of flutter_map and flutter_map_location_marker.
flutter_map_location_marker Lets me display a marker corresponding to the user's position, and orientation. It lets me also center the map automatically around the user's current position.

I would like however to stop the user tracking feature if the user pans the map around.

But both the user location changing, and map dragging end up triggering the same `onPositionChanged` event. I don't see a way to discern wether that event was due to panning or location update.

How could I discern both?

I have tried wrapping FlutterMap with a GestureDetector, but it does not catch map panning events, so I cannot snoop user actions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `hasGesture` parameter passed to the `onPositionChanged` callback to discern between user gesture and map controller/plugin.

Note that the "Follow FAB" example in their repository has this functionality: https://github.com/tlserver/flutter_map_location_marker/blob/master/example/lib/page/follow_fab_example.dart.